# How do you update ActiveX labels on multiple slides?

Tags: vba, label, powerpoint

I have an ActiveX Label on Slide 1 and I have this code:

```
Sub Addscore()
Score.Caption = (Score.Caption) + 10
End Sub
```

This adds 10 onto the ActiveX Label on Slide 1 no problem. I want that score to continue onto Slide 2, for example, so that on the next question(s) the score can be seen. I've tried just copying and pasting the ActiveX Label from Slide 1, but when I click on the button that contains the above macro, the score on Slide 2 doesn't change.

I've also tried calling the Label on Slide 2 a different name , Score1, and used this code:

```
Sub Addscore()
Score.Caption = (Score.Caption) + 10
Score1.Caption = (Score1.Caption) + 10
End Sub
```

But that didn't work either.

How can I get the score on a different slide to change as well? This code is taken from Slide1 on VBA.

Thanks,

Glenn

```
Sub Addscore()
Score.Caption = (Score.Caption) + 10
End Sub

Sub Addscore()
Score.Caption = (Score.Caption) + 10
Score1.Caption = (Score1.Caption) + 10
End Sub
```

I want the ActiveX Label on Slide 2 (or whatever slide it's on) to update the same as on Slide 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each slide has a label named "Score1" ... then would something like this work?

```
Option Explicit

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition <> SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide Then
        ActivePresentation.Slides(SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition).Shapes("Score1").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = _
            ActivePresentation.Slides(SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition - 1).Shapes("Score1").OLEFormat.Object.Caption + 10
    End If
End Sub
```